# How to count unique items in field in Access query and group them by [feildname]?

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct-values

[Given Table]

| Code | Status |
| --- | --- |
| AXYZ | Success |
| AXYZ | Success |
| AXYZ | Success |
| AXYZ |  |
| AXYZ |  |
| BXYZ | Success |
| BXYZ | Success |
| BXYZ | Success |
| BXYZ | Success |
| BXYZ |  |
| BXYZ |  |

SQL Command on Access

'''

```
SELECT [WERKS], count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM [Sheet1$]) FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY [WERKS]
```

'''

Expected Output

> AXYZ-2
>
> BXYZ-2

Actual Output :

> Error in FROM Clause

Comment: Thanks @JonasMetzler. I think you missed the part where I said that "DISTINCT (Feildname)" is not a supported command/query in MS Access. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Where did [WERKS] come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bust it into two groupings you can get the output you want

```
SELECT t1.Code, Count(t1.Code) AS NumStatus
FROM 
    (SELECT [Sheet1$].Code, [Sheet1$].Status
    FROM [Sheet1$]
    GROUP BY [Sheet1$].Code, [Sheet1$].Status)  AS t1
GROUP BY t1.Code;
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT COUNT(Code), Code FROM tableName WHERE Status not like 'Success' GROUP BY Code
```

This work for all Status that are not equal to 'Success'.

Comment: That only works for non-null entries

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT code, count(Distinct code , status) FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY code
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments you need to consider Null values

```
SELECT Count(Code) AS CountOfCode, Code
FROM tbl
WHERE [Status] Not Like 'Success' OR [Status] Is Null
GROUP BY Code;
```