# How to Select Distinct records then count them in C# Access database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table called TableA

[image: Table A]

I want my results to be like this

[image: Results]

**My code**

```
       string query = "Select Column2,Count(*) from (Select DISTINCT Column1 from TableA Group by Column2)"
```

I have tried a lot of solutions for apparently simple task but in vain. Been stuck from couple of hours. wish Access 2007 allow a simple Count(Distinct Column1) etc but it doesn't. Help and guidance is required.

Comment: When asking question it was showing a table but after posting, it isn't. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Your descriptions of the actual table and the wanted results don't make sense.

Comment: @funatparties I want distinct elements of column1 and count them and group them by column 2.

Comment: I answered a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72381794/2419128 - see if you can come up with better SQL from that. If not I can put something together

Comment: @dbmitch I tried your solution you mentioned earlier and now, Its giving 1in all rows as answer.

Comment: @dbmitch I did it. Not a better SQL but similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So dbmitch comment gave me headstart, I just changed it a bit. Here is the solution:

```
"Select Column2,Count(T1.Column1) AS Column3 from (Select Column2,Column1 from TableA Group by Column1,Column2) AS T1 Group by T1.Column2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT column2, Count(*) AS C FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM TableA GROUP BY column2) AS D;
```

Comment: Syntax error in "From" clause.